# Verifying there is no collision with a certain object after clicking it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, game-physics

I'm having trouble creating a way to check if the Player is NOT colliding with a certain 'waypoint' if I click that waypoint. I've set up 7 waypoints which the player will want to be able to move to.

Now I'm trying to write a piece of script that checks that AFTER the waypoint is clicked (onMouseDown) if there's a collision with the player. Because if that's the case it won't calculate the position to move to.

```
public class WayPointPositioner : MonoBehaviour {

private Vector3 wayPointPosition;
public GameObject playercheck;

//Check if object is clicked
void OnMouseDown () 
{
    Debug.Log ("Object Clicked " + GameObject.name);

    // Check if collision occurs with playercheck

    OnCollisionEnter(playercheck != Collision)
    {
        // If its the player, then return a new position for the player to move to for walking
        // Else debug that its not so
        if (playercheck.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {

            Debug.Log ("Object not colliding and retrieving position");

            wayPointPosition = new Vector3 (GameObject.X, GameObject.Y, 10);
            wayPointPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(wayPointPosition);

        }
        else
        {

            Debug.Log ("Object is colliding, no movement needed");

        }
    }
}

}
```

Now I've already figured out that `OnCollisionEnter` will not work. Because it requires the void-statement before it for it to function. However I have no clue how else I am able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it. Was just being an idiot.

Key is to use both functionalities, SEPERATELY. So I divided the tasks of checking for Mousedown and checking if the place is occupied by creating a seperate variable to ask true of false from to check it all.

```
public class WayPointPositioner : MonoBehaviour {

private Vector3 wayPointPosition;
private bool checkPlayerWaypointCollision;

void Start()
{
    wayPointPosition = transform.position;
}

void OnTriggerStay2D (Collider2D other) 
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        checkPlayerWaypointCollision = true;
    }
    else
    {
        checkPlayerWaypointCollision = false;
    }

}

//Check if object is clicked
void OnMouseDown () 
{

    // If its the player, then return a new position for the player to move to for walking
    // Else debug that its not so
        if (checkPlayerWaypointCollision == false)
        {

            Debug.Log ("Object not colliding and retrieving position");

            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y, 10);
            wayPointPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(wayPointPosition);

        }
        else
        {

            Debug.Log ("Object is colliding, no movement needed");

        }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just compare the position of the player and the way point. If equal then the player is there otherwise move to the way point. Hope I understand the problem right.

Comment: No, the waypoint system is there so that in the end the player character will move along the waypoints to the waypoint destination.  Example : He starts at Waypoint 02, and needs to go to Waypoint 06. then moves through 03-04-05 to get to 06.